# Bayesian optimization by groups

Tags: python, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I am currently comparing different models for a text classification task using tweets. Some of them are decision trees (random forests) and, since I augment my data periodically, I need to do hyperparameter's optimization quite often. This is why I moved to Bayesian optimization with [OPTUNA](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) (in Python), which really sped things up.

However, there is still a missing point that I can't figure out. My data has a group structure at the city level (all tweets produced in different cities), and the models are expected to do predictions at this level of aggregation. That is, I train on cities, then do predictions on a new city, feed back, re-train etc.

Due to this, I want the model evaluation to be at the city level and not in a mix of samples from different cities.

Using sckit-learn, I believe that [GroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold) should be the way to go. Does something similar exist for Bayesian optimization? Is there a way to let optuna know how my domains work?

Comment: I haven't been able to do this but I have been able to have a reasonable workaround: I wrote my cost-function such that the `Group*` `sklearn` iterator is used internally. So `Optuna` doesn't know that the cost is calculated in a group-aware manner but the value the cost function returns, are "group-aware". There is the [`OptunaSearchCV`](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.integration.OptunaSearchCV.html) but I didn't explore it a lot, it is potentially another avenue to explore.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! Could you maybe share a bit of the coding steps you did in order to achieve that?

Comment: We define a `GroupKFold` or something similar outside our cost function. Then within the function to refer to it  (e.g. when using `xgb.cv`) so we have the cost function look out of scope. We pass the cost function to `opt.optimize`.